# ERROR: "vue-class-component in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-calendars/src/calendar/calendar.component.js and 4 others"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, syncfusion

Today I started experimenting with syncfusion, but didn't get very far. I tried using "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-calendars", but I get the following error:

```
This dependency was not found:
vue-class-component in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-calendars/src/calendar/calendar.component.js, ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-calendars/src/datepicker/datepicker.component.js and 3 others
```

I tried installing "vue-class-component", but I get the 2 following warnings:

```
warning  in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-calendars/src/calendar/calendar.component.js

"export 'Options' was not found in 'vue-class-component'


warning  in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-calendars/src/daterangepicker/presets.directive.js

"export 'Vue' (imported as 'Vue3') was not found in 'vue-class-component'
```

What can I do to make it work?

Also, I should specify, I am on a vue 2.6.11 project.

Comment: For me installing `vue-class-component@8.0.0-rc.1` resolved the issue. Only this `8.0.0-rc.1` beta version. With Syncfusion v19.3.53. Also after installing `vue-class-component@8.0.0-rc.1` and updating Syncfusion try to delete `npm_modules` and `package-lock.json` and call `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue at our end in an earlier version, and it was resolved in the most recent version **19.2.0.49**. To resolve the reported issue, we suggest you that you upgrade your Syncfusion product version to the specified or newest version.

Please find the details from the below feedback.

https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/27318/syncfusion-vue-components-are-not-working-in-vue-2